# Prestosql/trino on EMR scaling down kills the queries

Tags: amazon-emr, presto, trino, starburst

I have a presto cluster on EMR. We also have auto scaling policy in place based on AWS Clouldwatch metrics. We have a issue when cluster scale-down the nodes, it doesn't wait for queries running on those nodes to complete. It just kills all queries and scale down. There is a property which graciously shut down the nodes, can be used in cluster configuration, but this has its limitations. It doesn't work with trino or prestoSql.This only works for Prestodb.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/presto-graceful-autoscale.html

I have also explored the `cooldown` period in autoscaling policies but none of them seems to be working for our cluster.
I am wondering is this a known issue for prestosql/trino

Comment: I suspect you've already seen these by now, have you looked at these blogs, which address your problem? https://medium.com/@saharghya/presto-trino-graceful-scale-down-complete-setup-on-aws-ec2-autoscaling-group-132b279b5177 and https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/custom-downscaler-for-trino-cluster-on-google-cloud-243f64112b86/. In a nutshell you need to DIY or use Starburst does this OOB.

Answer (score 0):

AWS created a GitHub repo [Amazon EMR - Trino Autoscale](https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-trino-autoscale) in March 2023 which I think will help.

In the readme, it mentions

> This project provides a custom auto-autoscaling for Amazon EMR on EC2 clusters running with Trino. The package support out of the box Instance Groups and Instance Fleets clusters with On Demand / SPOT instances.
>
> ...
>
> In order to use this utility, it is recommended to enable [Trino fault-tolerant execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/trino-ft.html) to avoid query failures during resize operations.